# Anaconda: Installing opencv in tensorflow environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, conda

in Anaconda3 (python3.7) I made an Tensorflow environment named tf. Now I tried to install OpenCv into this environment. I tried several:

`conda install --name tf opencv
conda install --name tf -c conda-forge opencv`

I tried also inside the tf folder:
`pip install opencv-python`

all runs and installed something. But when I try to run my code the error appears that it couldn't find cv2.

I import it with 
`import cv2 as cv`.

I run the code through Conda in  Visual Studio Code. Ans I selcted the Interpreter `Path Python3.7.6 64-bit('tf':conda)`

The installation of numpy and matplotlib into this environment worked.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong? Or how I can combine these two, OpenCV and Tensorflow, through anaconda?

Thanks a lot

Comment: when you say `inside the tf folder`, what do you mean ? Normally you should run the `pip install opencv-python` after [**activating** the conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment). See the instructions for windows. When activated, your prompt should change to show `(tf)` in front. Then you can `pip install`

Comment: Try creating the environment from an environment file where you specify all the packages.

Answer (score 2):

Use following commands

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow
conda activate tf
```

Then use

```
pip install opencv-python
```